# Dask Dataframe sum of column always returning scalar

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dask

I've created a Dask Dataframe (called "df") and the column with index "11" has integer values:

```
In [62]: df[11]
Out[62]:
Dask Series Structure:
npartitions=42
    int64
      ...
    ...
      ...
      ...
Name: 11, dtype: int64
Dask Name: getitem, 168 tasks
```

I'm trying to sum these with:

```
df[11].sum()
```

I get `dd.Scalar<series-..., dtype=int64>` returned. Despite researching what this might mean I'm still at odds as to why I'm not getting a numerical value returned. How can I translate this into its numerical value?

Comment: `df[11].sum().compute()` not working too?

Comment: Works great! I can't find .compute() in the documentation for .sum(), I must have missed something here. Or anywhere in particular in the documentation for dask. So I'm not sure why this has worked. Would you mind pointing me in the right direction?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you need [`compute`](http://docs.dask.org/en/latest/dataframe-api.html#dask.dataframe.DataFrame.compute) for telling `Dask` to process everything that came before:

> **compute**(**kwargs)
> Compute this dask collection
>
> This turns a lazy Dask collection into its in-memory equivalent. For example a Dask.array turns into a numpy.array() and a Dask.dataframe turns into a Pandas dataframe. The entire dataset must fit into memory before calling this operation.

```
df[11].sum().compute()
```